# Visual studio 2008 Illegal characters in path

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am running on application in Visual Studio 2008 in new laptop (windows 2010). in my old system (windows 2008) was running fine. Even my other team member able to run it. I am getting below error

[image]

I tried to run same application in VS 2013 its  runs fine.
from other post I already install StyleCop . still the same. Anything I can do to get it work? any advice !!

Answer (score 0):

to get that work I created new working folder from VSS and get latest code from VSS and then run the code from new working folder after that all fine.